# Htaccess redirect wiout trailing slash is working but with it is not

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress website. And I want to redirect a URL to another 3rd party domain. The issue is that destination domain cannot have trailing slash.

So I want to redirect `http://www.domain.com/xyzxyzxyz` to `http://3rd-party-domain.com/?something`

It's working fine for without trailing slash request urls

```
http://www.domain.com/xyzxyzxyz -> http://3rd-party-domain.com/?something
```

but when I try `http://www.domain.com/xyzxyzxyz/` then it does not work because it adds trailing slash in destination URL too, which gives error.

I have tried these rewrite rules

```
Redirect 301 /xyzxyzxyz http://3rd-party-domain.com/?something
Redirect 301 /xyzxyzxyz/ http://3rd-party-domain.com/?something
```

Not working :(

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `RedirectMatch` for its regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xyzxyzxyz/?$ http://3rd-party-domain.com/?something
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But will it not redirect /xyzxyzxyz/abcd also? I do not want that.